# Import modules after compilation with py2exe

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I compiled a python executable with py2exe and want to import a python module by a user input.

```
userinput = input("Enter module name")
module = __import__(userinput)
```

Does this work? Or is there another way to import a module after the file is compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(userinput)
```